# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial, android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE only on kitkat version

Tags: android, sipdroid

i am developing SIP application and it running successfully but getting a security Permission Denial Exception of PHONE_STATE only on KitKat Android version.
Do anyone know what is the reason, Please help me to find a solution.

Here is some part of code:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
        intent.putExtra("state",state);
        if (number != null)
            intent.putExtra("incoming_number", number);
        intent.putExtra(mContext.getString(R.string.app_name), true);
        mContext.sendBroadcast(intent, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
```

LogCat :-

```
05-28 01:48:52.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2860): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 01:48:52.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2860): Process: org.sipdroid.sipua, PID: 2860
05-28 01:48:52.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2860): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission             Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE from pid=2860,   uid=10051
05-28 01:48:52.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2860):     at   android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1461)
05-28 01:48:52.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2860):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1415)
05-28 01:48:52.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2860):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:2373)
05-28 01:48:52.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2860):     at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast(ContextImpl.java:1141)
05-28 01:48:52.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2860):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:370)
05-28 01:48:52.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2860):     at org.sipdroid.sipua.ui.Receiver.broadcastCallStateChanged(Receiver.java:496)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it. On KitKat only system services are allowed to send broadcast.

You need to find a workaround for that.

Answer (score 0):

change your makeCallWithOptions() method of SipService class as follows...

```
public void makeCallWithOptions(final String callee, final int accountId, final Bundle options)
            throws RemoteException {
        SipService.this.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(SipManager.PERMISSION_USE_SIP, null);
        //We have to ensure service is properly started and not just binded
        SipService.this.startService(new Intent(SipService.this, SipService.class));

        if(pjService == null) {
            Log.e(THIS_FILE, "Can't place call if service not started");
            // TODO - we should return a failing status here
            return;
        }

        if(!supportMultipleCalls) {
            // Check if there is no ongoing calls if so drop this request by alerting user
            SipCallSession activeCall = pjService.getActiveCallInProgress();
            if(activeCall != null) {
                if(!CustomDistribution.forceNoMultipleCalls()) {
                    notifyUserOfMessage(R.string.not_configured_multiple_calls);
                    Log.d("call......", "makecallwithoption");
                }
                return;
            }
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(SipManager.ACTION_SIP_CALL_LAUNCH);
        intent.putExtra(SipProfile.FIELD_ID, accountId);
        intent.putExtra(SipManager.EXTRA_SIP_CALL_TARGET, callee);
        intent.putExtra(SipManager.EXTRA_SIP_CALL_OPTIONS, options);
        sendOrderedBroadcast (intent , SipManager.PERMISSION_USE_SIP, mPlaceCallResultReceiver, null,  Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
    }
```

Add following broadcast receiver.....
    private BroadcastReceiver mPlaceCallResultReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

```
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {
            final Bundle extras =  intent.getExtras();
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if(extras == null) {
                Log.e(THIS_FILE, "No data in intent retrieved for call");
                return;
            }
            if(!SipManager.ACTION_SIP_CALL_LAUNCH.equals(action)) {
                Log.e(THIS_FILE, "Received invalid action " + action);
                return;
            }

            final int accountId = extras.getInt(SipProfile.FIELD_ID, -2);
            final String callee = extras.getString(SipManager.EXTRA_SIP_CALL_TARGET);
            final Bundle options = extras.getBundle(SipManager.EXTRA_SIP_CALL_OPTIONS);
            if(accountId == -2 || callee == null) {
                Log.e(THIS_FILE, "Invalid rewrite " + accountId);
                return;
            }

            getExecutor().execute(new SipRunnable() {
                @Override
                protected void doRun() throws SameThreadException {
                    pjService.makeCall(callee, accountId, options);
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

In class UAStateReceiver change the following

```
private void onBroadcastCallState(final SipCallSession callInfo) {
        SipCallSession publicCallInfo = new SipCallSession(callInfo);
        Intent callStateChangedIntent = new Intent(SipManager.ACTION_SIP_CALL_CHANGED);
        callStateChangedIntent.putExtra(SipManager.EXTRA_CALL_INFO, publicCallInfo);
        pjService.service.sendBroadcast(callStateChangedIntent, SipManager.PERMISSION_USE_SIP);

    }
```

and......

```
private void broadCastAndroidCallState(String state, String number) {
        // Android normalized event
        if(!Compatibility.isCompatible(19)) {
            // Not allowed to do that from kitkat
            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
            intent.putExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE, state);
            if (number != null) {
                intent.putExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER, number);
            }
            intent.putExtra(pjService.service.getString(R.string.app_name), true);
            pjService.service.sendBroadcast(intent, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        }

    }
```

and it will able to make call in android 4.4.2 Happy coading :)